# passing a pointer to a pointer in c function by value

Tags: c, function, pointers

`fid_table` is a pointer to an array of `fid_list` pointers.

I am trying to initialize the `fid_table` to `NULL`s in a separate function. My understanding that fid_table is copied by value but it is a pointer so that should not be the problem.

```
fid_list **fid_table;
fid_table_init(fid_table);
assert(fid_table[0] == NULL);
```

The function `fid_table_init` is defined as follows:

```
void fid_table_init(fid_list **fid_table){
    fid_table = (fid_list **) malloc(HTABLE_SIZE * sizeof(fid_list *));
    for(int i = 0; i < HTABLE_SIZE; i++){
        fid_table[i] = NULL;
    }
}
```

Can someone elaborate on why this assertion fails?

Comment: Is that C or C++? In C you should not cast `voiud *`, in C++ you have to. Please choose one language.

Comment: Ok, I will not ask why you did add the C++ tag then. So: Standard warning: do not cast `void *`.

Comment: "My understanding that fid_table is copied by value but it is a pointer so that should not be the problem." No. You're probably confusing a pointer with an array. You will have to take a pointer to `fid_table` when calling `fid_table_init`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define the function the following way

```
void fid_table_init(fid_list ***fid_table){
    *fid_table = (fid_list **) malloc(HTABLE_SIZE * sizeof(fid_list *));
    for(int i = 0; i < HTABLE_SIZE; i++){
        ( *fid_table )[i] = NULL;
    }
}
```

And call it like

```
fid_table_init( &fid_table );
```

In the original function the pointer is passed by value that is the function deals with a copy of the pointer. So any changes of the copy do not influence on the original pointer.

Take into account that function's parameters are its local variables. So inside the function you allocated a memory and assigned its address to a local variable of the function. It is the local variable that was assigned not the original pointer. After exiting the function its local variables will be destroyed. The original pointer knows nothing what was done with its copy

Comment: That looks somewhat awful (does not imply it is wrong!). Tripple star function.

Comment: @Olaf Imagine it like a three stars cognac.:)

Comment: Congratulations: you have unlocked the [thee star programmer](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer) badge!

Comment: What I don't understand is why passing a copy of a pointer does not work. if fid_table holds the address x. then fid_table[0] is the the address x in the memory. Passing a copy of the value of x to another variable and indexing the first element should be the same. Is there anything I am missing here?

Comment: In order to modify a passed variable within a function, it _must_ be passed through a pointer. It's that simple. Whether it itself was a pointer (to a pointer, to a pointer) before that does not change this fact at all.

Comment: @Keeto Function's parameters are its local variables. So inside the function you allocated a memory and assigned its address to a local variable of the function. It is the local variable that was assigned not the original pointer. After exiting the function its local variables will be destroyed. The original pointer knows nothing what was done with its copy.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Thanks a lot I got it!

Comment: ...and then a reference is _basically_ just a pointer plus automatic dereferencing and minus the abilities to be null or reassigned ;-) Even in C++ it can be difficult to choose between them in many situations.

Answer (score 5):

In the `fid_table_init` function, `fid_table` is a local variable that is initialized with the value passed from the caller. The `malloc` line changes the value of the local variable, it does not change the value of `fid_table` in the caller, so the calling code never sees the pointer returned from `malloc`.

The easiest way to fix the code is to return the new value of the pointer from the `fid_table_init` function, and assign it to the `fid_table` in the caller.

```
fid_list **fid_table = fid_table_init();
assert(fid_table[0] == NULL);
```

---

```
fid_list **fid_table_init( void )
{
    fid_list **temp = malloc(HTABLE_SIZE * sizeof(fid_list *));
    for(int i = 0; i < HTABLE_SIZE; i++){
        temp[i] = NULL;
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: Glad to help, happy coding!